# Can villagers open chests?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to be able to get bread to villagers without having to do it manually, and I was wondering if they could open chests to get it themselves.

Answer (score 3):

## Villagers cannot open chests.

It may be possible for you to put bread into a dropper (or dispenser) and then automatically activate the dropper with a redstone clock, but you need a good setup for this to solve your problem.

Comment: It does likely solve the problem. It's commonly used in automatic villager breeders.

Comment: @FabianRöling I changed the wording a bit now

Comment: So, it would be pointless to add chests to the houses or job-site structures in the "compound" I'm building hoping that the villagers might put stuff in there for me to loot later. <sigh>